# Using Seaborn's PairGrid to plot many variables against one

Tags: seaborn

I'd like to visualize how one variable in my dataset correlates with 13 other variables. Seaborn's PairGrid allows me to do this fairly easily, but the resulting figure ends up being a single row of graphs with 13 columns. For FacetGrid, there is a wrap_cols parameter that can be passed to make this type of plot look more attractive. Any suggestions for how to implement this column wrap with PairGrid?

The code I'm currently using to generate the 1x13 plot:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(dataframe, hue=classes, y_vars=var_of_interest, x_vars = list_of_13_covariates)
g.map(plt.scatter)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PairGrid` object does not have a `col_wrap` parameter.

See the docs here:
http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.PairGrid.html#seaborn.PairGrid

Comment: Thanks, I had discovered that. I’m looking for advice on how I might best emulate that parameter for PairGrid, since it doesn’t exist.

Comment: @exark you'll have to drop down into matplotlib and create your own layout of axes.